# Is there a program to draw images using spritesheets?

Tags: image-editor, drawing

I have a spritesheet with images of my world (I'm trying to create a simple 2D city).

Is there any program in which I load my spritesheet and then I can draw a new image using the sprites? (or if I can configure Photoshop for that, how do I do that?)

Basically, I want an image in a grid and fill each square with a sprite from my spritesheet.

I know I should write my own program for that, but i'm just curious.

Comment: "I know I should write my own program for that, but i'm just curious" - don't be curious - start coding

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of tutorials such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BT6Jdz4J4hU) available on how to use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to create & edit sprite sheets.

There is even a plugin to help called [Narly Sprite](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27513).

Exported as a grid sprite sheet:

[image: grid sprite sheet]

Flattened and exported as an animated gif:

[image: animated gif]

*I also noticed that one of the stretch goals for the current [Krita](https://krita.org/) funding campaign on [kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/krita/krita-free-paint-app-lets-make-it-faster-than-phot) is to add sprite sheets to it so if you prefer working with a tablet and are willing to help fund development you could chip in, (**N.B.** They have reached the base goal and people who hit some funding levels get to prioritize the stretch goals.)*

On the other hand if you already have your sprite set in any of a number of standard image formats, (such as gif), you can load it in gimp and use the [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml) Array & Tiles -> Montage filter to automatically produce a grid of your images or you can select the images from individual layers to copy and paste, or to use as a brush, in another image.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to draw an image USING spritesheets. Do you know any program that can do that?

Comment: @Ricjssubtil - Yes Gimp - see last paragraph above!